# ListView auto-update in Android?

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView in my app, and every week, I am adding a new item to it. But I don't want my user to update that whole application just for that. Is there anyway to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data for list view is typically driven using an adapter, which intern pulls it from a database/some other form of storage.

As long as you put the data in your storage, and have code to pull everything and give it to your adapter, I think the list view will display everything.

Just make sure you call notifyDatasetChanged().

Please refer to documentation here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Do you know any site or links that will teach me this whole concept?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, have the application check your website on startup (or after startup in the background or something like that).  If there's new data, download it and store it in some sort of local storage.

Comment: Do you know any site or link that can help me to accomplish this?